# Angular error: ngb-carousel is not a known element

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a caroussel with ngb-carousel but i got the error:
'ngb-carousel' is not a know element

1. If 'ngb-carousel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-carousel' is a web component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Ngmodule.schemas of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: Have you imported the `import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` module? Can you share some code ?

Comment: From ng-bootstrap 9 you can also only import the `{NgbCarouselModule}`. @HalalWalker, remember that you need import the module in the **same** module you declare your component

Answer (score 1):

Import the Carousel module in the `app.module.ts` file.

```
import { NgbCarouselModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    NgbCarouselModule,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```